# When should I start using flyway, at the start of development or at the first release?

Tags: database, spring, flyway

I am starting a project with spring boot and I do not know when should I have to start using flyway.

Just right now, at the beginning or when at the first release?

Probably this is a newbie question but I have heard of flyway base this weekend and is such a new thing to me.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to use Flyway as early as possible. This gives you the opportunity to get used to the workflow and to make mistakes in your development environment.

I would start to use it when your domain or entity model has reached a first stable version. By a first stable version of your domain model I mean when all JPA entities and their relations are implemented as you want them to be.

Then generate the DDL using e.g Hibernate `SchemaExport` and create your first Flyway migration script containing all the `CREATE TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE` statements.

I recommend this procedure since it allows you to define version 1.0 of your database. Every change on JPA entities will possibly force you to migrate your database. Therefore I suggest to first design your entities and then write the migration script.

Hope this helps. Enjoy.

Comment: When you say "when your domain or entity model has reached a first stable version" you mean when all the model is created and ready to use or when a small part of the functional requirements is working? For example, when I have working user registration before the other functionality is even developed. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

As @saw303 suggested above I would recommend as early as possible and personally for me from the first change to the database.

By introducing this at the earliest viable point it will allow you to refine your build and deployment processes early which will save you in the long run. It also reinforces one of the key principles that changes shouldn't be applied to the database out with flyway.

This might sound counter intuitive at a early stage when the structure may be unstable and likely to change but by having the scripts in place it allows you to make use of the clean task followed by a migrate. This would drop all objects and recreate based on your scripts which is a time saver and depending on the size of your database would likely just take seconds to do.

I'd also recommend you carefully consider your approach to versioning and how you manage different environments especially if some scripts would only apply to Dev or test etc. The approach we took recently was to use the locations property to specify multiple paths. Each environments used a common folder followed by a specific location for that environment.

I'd recommend watching this webinar as it'll give you some good points to consider on how best to implement flyway.

[Database Migration Patterns with Flyway](http://info.trifork.com/flyway.html)

Bottom line is there are lots of ways to implement flyway to suit your needs and there won't necessarily be a one size fits all but the earlier you get started with it in your project you'll learn what works best and configure accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I am relatively new to the "professional" programming and at the moment I do not know how to use development enviroments. I am currently working alone in my first big project so I am learning as I walk. It is nice to see people spending time to help other people. Thanks a lot cdavid and saw303.